# Connection timed out error in JMeter Perfmon

Tags: linux, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, health-monitoring

I'm trying to extract server monitoring from my Linux server. I'm using JMeter Plugin Perfmon Metrics collector and had installed the Server Agent in the Linux server.

However, I get this error:

[image]

If I want to extract the graph only, is it necessary to include the test script (jmx file) as well? For now, I didn't include any jmx script since I just want to extract server health from Linux.

I also checked if Java already installed in the Linux, and yes it exist in the server. I also had started the serveragent.sh in linux.

[image]

How do I know what's the real issue here? Appreciate if someone can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the .jmx script, but you need a [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers), Listener per se won't work, it works only in conjunction with a [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) so you can add i.e. a [Dummy Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/DummySampler/) with response time equal to your metric collection window (1 second, 5 seconds, whatever) and the listener should start working.

With regards to the connection issue: make sure that

1. the [Server Agent](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent) is running on the machine you want to monitor
2. the port matches (default port for the server agent is `4444`
3. the connection is not blocked by i.e. operating system [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing))

More information: [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)